# JpaRepository resolving the wrong table names

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Have been breaking my head over this for a couple of days now.

I have the following *maven, multi-module* project structure (leaving out a lot of stuff):

**common**

common-repository
--> com.example.common.repository
---> EventRepository

common-repository-model --> entity classes

*[other packages]*

**concrete-package-A**

webapp
-> com.example.A
--> FirstApplication

*[other packages, including service layer which calls repos]*

**concrete-package-B**

webapp
-> com.example.B
--> SecondApplication

repository
-> com.example.repository
--> SecondAppRepositoryConfigA, SecondAppRepositoryConfigB

*[other packages, including service layer which calls repos]*

-

Event Repository (a JPA repo):

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
    List<Event> findAllByExample_IdOrderByEventTime(Long exampleId);   
}
```

FirstApplication:

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
@SpringBootApplication
@EnablePrometheusEndpoint
@EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.common.repository", ...})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"..."})
@EnableEntityLinks
public class FirstApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   [some beans, none related to repo stuff]
}
```

SecondApplication is the entry point and contains some beans, none of them important here.

SecondAppRepositoryConfigA contains beans and config used by the repository layer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager",
    basePackages = {..., "com.example.common.repository"}
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SecondAppRepositoryConfigA {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Bean(name = "myJpaProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("example.jpa")
    @Primary
    public JpaProperties myJpaProperties() {
        return new JpaProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "myDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        return (DataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().type(DataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "myEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myEntityManagerFactory(JpaProperties myJpaProperties) {
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(myJpaProperties);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = builder
            .dataSource(myDataSource())
            .packages("....repository.....entities",...)
            .persistenceUnit("myPersistenceUnit")
            .build();
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "myTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager myTransactionManager(@Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory orderEntityManager) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(orderEntityManager);
    }

    private EntityManagerFactoryBuilder createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(@Qualifier("myJpaProperties") JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = createJpaVendorAdapter(jpaProperties);
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(jpaVendorAdapter, jpaProperties.getProperties(), this.persistenceUnitManager);
    }

    private JpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter(JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        AbstractJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(jpaProperties.isShowSql());
        adapter.setDatabase(jpaProperties.getDatabase());
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform(jpaProperties.getDatabasePlatform());
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

SecondAppRepositoryConfigB is also used by the second application, but is less important, mainly used for testing:

```
@Configuration
public class SecondAppRepositoryConfigB {

    @Bean(name = "secondMyDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.datasource")
    public DataSource secondMyDataSource() {
        return (DataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().type(DataSource.class).build();
    }
```

Example of an entity from the common section:

```
@Data
@EntityListeners(EventListener.class)
@NamedQuery(name = "Event.findAll", query = "select e from Event e order by e.eventTime desc")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = Type.IMAGE_VALUE, value = ImageEvent.class),
    ...
})
@Entity
public abstract class Event {

    @Id
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
        ...
    )
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Type type;

    private String displayedTime;


    ...
}
```

Wiring of beans etc. seems to be OK.

But when I use the JPA repo from the common package in my first application (the one that only uses JPA repositories and leaves the rest to spring+hibernate), hibernate queries use the correct entity names. I.e. it uppercases and uses _ instead of camelcase.

However, in the second application (the one that has a custom entity manager which I need for more complex queries), hibernate does not use camel case at all, generating SQL like:

```
select event0_.id as id2_7_, event0_.displayedTime as displayedTime3_7_, ... 
from correctschema.Event event0_ left outer join correctschema.ImageEvent event0_3_ on event0_.id= ...
```

Event instead of EVENT, ImageEvent instead of IMAGE_EVENT, displayedTime instead of DISPLAY_TIME, etc.

I am also seeing stuff like this in the second application logging:

```
o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder         : Bind entity com.example.repository.entities.events.TextEvent on table TextEvent
```

Whereas in the first application logs, it says "on table text_event".

Really no clue what the difference is between both modules. A third application is also running fine with JPA repos, using a mixture of the above approaches. I have looked at setting a different naming strategy, or changing the dialect, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Annotated entities with `@Table(name = "concrete databasename")`

Comment: This seems related to the default naming strategy. You should be able to  customize it using EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.properties() or JpaProperties.Naming

Comment: LppEdd: I tried to set the naming strategy using spring properties (spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy). Did not work.
XtremeBaumer: I already did that and it does work. However, I would prefer not doing this, especially since application A works fine without the additional annotations. Also afraid that I would just be hiding some underlying issue by fixing the symptoms, not the disease.